# EXCEL VBA Filter function (non 365) for use in drop down validation

Tags: excel

I'm using standard Excel for a small issue and I want to get a dropdown (validation) that uses a filtered table. Is this possible and what type needs to be returned in order to make it happen.

[image]

Comment: No, it's not possible. You can only use a range on a sheet, or a literal delimited string.

Comment: You have to use filtering function to a sheet then can refer that ranges to name manager.